# Conditions on EM wave complex exponentials and generalizations

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, complex-numbers

The complex exponential ansatz for electromagnetic waves is utilized for algebraic simplicity. However, we admit that, depending on the setup for the ansatz, only the real or imaginary part is of physical concern. In various scenarios, e.g. total internal reflection, the Maxwell equations in (linear, homogeneous) media, as well as boundary condition matching imposes constraints. For instance, $\alpha = \beta$. We typically address these constraints the complex exponential form, but in terms of what is physically relevant, we really only care if $Re[\alpha] = Re[\beta]$, so $Im[\alpha] \neq Im[\beta]$ should be allowed, but we tend to impose the equality on this relation anyway. My question is, why? Is it because if it does not lead to a trivial solution/contradictions, imposing $\alpha = \beta$ in generality is mathematically more effective while ensuring the reality condition holds? Is it nothing more than a mathematical tool that exploits the linearity of the Maxwell equations? Are there additional real, physical solutions to EM wave conditions that are not observed by treating $\alpha = \beta$ in general? I know the answer is no due to uniqueness, but how I can mathematically justify that?

Comment: It is just easier. Because while we often only take the Re part as physically there, we actually could also only take the Im part as physically there. You can actually also work with circularly polarised light and have both contributions being physically there, in which case we actually do require both paths to equal. Imposing equality is just the mentally less taxing thing to do, and no need to explain so much. Very rarely do people like you appear to ask this kind of questions.